# Ray | AttributeError: 'BroadModel' object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: python, deep-learning, hyperparameters, ray

I am using ray tune to find to optimal hyperparameters value for this model:

```
class BroadModel(tune.Trainable):
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
    def build_model(self, config):
        global convB2, drop2, convA2, poolA, poolB 
        window_size = 200
        self.x_gyro, self.x_acc, x_mag, q = load_data_train()
        self.Att_quat = Att_q(q)
        self.x_gyro_t, self.x_acc_t, x_mag_t, q_t = load_data_test()
        self.Att_quat_t = Att_q(q_t)

        self.x_gyro, self.x_acc, self.Att_quat = shuffle(self.x_gyro, self.x_acc, self.Att_quat)
        x1 = Input((window_size, 3), name='x1')
        x2 = Input((window_size, 3), name='x2')
        convA1 = Conv1D(config["Conv1DA"],11,padding='same',activation='relu')(x1)
        for i in range(config["Conv1DAn"]):
            if i > 0: 
                convA2 = Conv1D(config[f'Conv1DAn_{i}'],11,padding='same',activation='relu')(convA1)
        poolA = MaxPooling1D(3)(convA1)
        
        
        convB1 = Conv1D(config["Conv1DB"],11,padding='same',activation='relu')(x2)
        for i in range(config["Conv1DBn"]):
            if i > 0:
                convB2 = Conv1D(config[f'Conv1DBn_{i}'],11,padding='same',activation='relu')(convB1)
        poolB = MaxPooling1D(3)(convB1)
        AB = concatenate([poolA, poolB])
        
        lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(config["LSTM1"], return_sequences=True))(AB)
        drop1 = Dropout(config['dropout'])(lstm1)
        for i in range(config['LSTMn']):
            if i > 0:
                lstm2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(config[f'LSTMn_{i}'], return_sequences=True))(drop1)
                drop1 =  Dropout(config['dropout'])(lstm2)   
        lstm2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(config['LSTMn_l']))(drop1)
        drop2 =  Dropout(config['dropout'])(lstm2)
        y1_pred = Dense(4,kernel_regularizer='l2')(drop2)
        model = Model(inputs =[x1, x2], outputs = [y1_pred])
        return model
    def setup(self, config):
        
        model = self.build_model(config)
    
        model.compile(
            optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=config['lr']),
            loss=quaternion_mean_multiplicative_error,
            metrics=[quaternion_mean_multiplicative_error],
        )
        self.model = model
        return model
```

But whenever I scale up my network by increasing the size of each layer from 50 to 100 or more or increasing the number of iterations from 10~20 to more than 40 I get some weird errors such as

```
> Failure # 1 (occurred at 2022-09-05_12-04-07)
> [36mray::ResourceTrainable.train()[39m (pid=35719,
> ip=192.168.91.120, repr=<ray.tune.trainable.util.BroadModel object at
> 0x7f478f107c40>)   File
> "/home/ssrc/asq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/tune/trainable/trainable.py",
> line 347, in train
>     result = self.step()   File "ray_test.py", line 258, in step
>     self.model.fit( AttributeError: 'BroadModel' object has no attribute 'model'
```

This is the tunning code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import ray
    from ray.tune.schedulers import PopulationBasedTraining
    

    pbt = PopulationBasedTraining(
        perturbation_interval=600,
        hyperparam_mutations={
            "dropout": tune.uniform(0.1,0.5),
            "lr": tune.uniform(1e-5,1e-3),
            "Conv1DA": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DAn": tune.choice([0,1,2,3]),
            "Conv1DAn_1": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DAn_2": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DAn_3": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DB": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DBn": tune.choice([0,1,2,3]),
            "Conv1DBn_1": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DBn_2": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DBn_3": tune.randint(10,15),
            "LSTM1": tune.randint(10,15),
            "LSTMn": tune.choice([0,1,2,3]),
            "LSTMn_1": tune.randint(10,15),
            "LSTMn_2": tune.randint(10,15),
            "LSTMn_3": tune.randint(10,15),
            "LSTMn_l": tune.randint(10,15),
           },
        
    )
    resources_per_trial = {"cpu": 10 , "gpu": 0}
    tuner = tune.Tuner(
         tune.with_resources(
        BroadModel,
        resources=resources_per_trial),
        run_config=air.RunConfig(
            name="BroadPBT"+timestr,
            stop={"training_iteration": 50},
        ),
        tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(
            reuse_actors=True,
            scheduler=pbt,
            metric="loss",
            mode="min",
            num_samples=2 ,
            
        ),
        param_space={
            "finish_fast": False,
            "batch_size": 1000,
            "epochs": 200,
            "dropout": tune.uniform(0.1,0.5),
            "lr": tune.uniform(1e-5,1e-3),
            "Conv1DA": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DAn": tune.choice([0,1,2,3]),
            "Conv1DAn_1": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DAn_2": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DAn_3": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DB": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DBn": tune.choice([0,1,2,3]),
            "Conv1DBn_1": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DBn_2": tune.randint(10,15),
            "Conv1DBn_3": tune.randint(10,15),
            "LSTM1": tune.randint(10,15),
            "LSTMn": tune.choice([0,1,2,3]),
            "LSTMn_1": tune.randint(10,15),
            "LSTMn_2": tune.randint(10,15),
            "LSTMn_3": tune.randint(10,15),
            "LSTMn_l": tune.randint(10,15),
            
            
        },
    )
    #tune.run(resources_per_trial={'gpu': 1}, tuner)
    tuner.fit()
```

What should I do?
As I mentioned before if I change the interaction numbers to less than 20, I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to your class:

```
def reset_config(self, new_config):
        self.config = new_config
        self.build_model(new_config)
        return True
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using PBT to tune the network size is that it tries to modify these parameters *mid-run* - and this is usually undefined behavior. The reason for that is that you'll either drop layers/nodes that potentially contain relevant information (when downscaling) or add randomly initialized nodes that do not contain any information (when upscaling) and in either case will usually render the rest of the network useless.

For PBT, you can mutate any parameters *except* for the network parameters.

Comment: Thanks. What do you recommend? Do you mean I must use another hyperparameter tunning algorithm?

Comment: It really depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve, how large your training job is (e.g. how long it takes or how many resources it needs), etc.

Here is a guide that could help you with this: https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/faq.html#which-search-algorithm-scheduler-should-i-choose